# Is it a good or bad thing to allow hot-loading of changes of game rules without official updates and restarts of server and clients?

Tags: game-design, architecture

I’m working on such feature for my project that we allow the game designer to tweak game rules, from small things like item prices to bigger like probability for different randomizations,  while the game is running, and the changes immediately get pushed to server and client in code by just reassigning variable references in code at runtime. There are some doubts in the team from wide range of concerns such that doing so might cause a limbo period of overlapped old and new rules as different variables gets picked up at different concurrent sessions at different phases(such game rules are read-only), and possible interrupted player experiences. Can anyone know or have similar experiences share your insights? Thanks!!

Comment: This isn't necessarily universally good or bad, just good or bad at meeting a specific set of requirements. So, describe your requirements for this feature, and we can evaluate appropriate solutions. If you're concerned about overlapping use of the rules or interrupted experiences, consider instead asking how to solve those problems.

Comment: The requirement is to let the designer to see quickly how changes of game rules play out

Comment: Just as something like player position can be reasonably consistent across the network; so could rules be if you use as similar technique for storing rules and transmitting updates.

Comment: You can select a group of players as canaries and only push experimental rules to them (possibly disrupt their gaming experience). Once the designers think a rule change is good, you can push the rule change as a regular update to the remaining players.  This limmits the negative impact of realtime modifyable rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a great idea to have this ability during the development of your game, because it would allow a quite fast testing cycle. When your designers want to toy with the balance of certain variables, they don't need to restart (or even recompile and redeploy) the server after every little change. They can see the change immediately while they are playing the game. Fast test cycles are a **huge** accelerator to the design process. So if you see a feasible way to integrate this into your software architecture without having it bend over backwards, then it might be really worth it in the long run.

How much use you make of this when the game is in production is a different question. Server restarts are annoying for everyone involved, so the more you can do without requiring a restart the better. But the concerns of your team members are valid. You don't want to break stuff due to weird interactions while new rulesets are being applied. This is, however, more of a social problem than a technical problem. **You** need to teach your admins what settings they can tweak while the game is running and what kind of tweaks they should rather do while the server is offline.

In the end, dummying out the ability to do live-changes to those settings where live-changes aren't going to work properly anyway should be trivial.